# Tailwind/CSS on scroll transition and on hover are sharing the same duration

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have the following usecase.

1. Animate cards when they in view for the first time ( appear animations ), and I toggle a class when `react-intersection-observer` toggles `inView` boolean
2. Animate scaleup when cards are hovered over

Currently, the appear transition lasts 500ms, and the hover SHOULD last 100ms but it shares the same duration as the appear transition so the hover became 500ms long as well.

I am using [react-intersection-observer](https://github.com/thebuilder/react-intersection-observer), [TWMerge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tailwind-merge) (Utility function to efficiently merge Tailwind CSS classes in JS without style conflicts.) and [CLSX](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx) ( utility for constructing className strings conditionally.)

Here's my card

```
   <InView triggerOnce threshold={0.3}>
      {({ ref, inView }) => (
        <li
          ref={ref}
          className={clsxm(
            'post-card rounded-md bg-secondary shadow-md lg:rounded-lg',
            'fade-slide-bottom',
            { 'in-view': inView } // applies in-view class if inView is true
          )}
        >
```

And the classes mentioned above

```
.post-card {
  @apply shadow-xl hover:scale-[1.02] hover:shadow-primary;
  transition: shadow 0.7s, transform 0.1s;
}


.fade-slide {
  @apply opacity-0 duration-500 ease-linear;
  transition-property: opacity, transform;
}

.fade-slide-bottom {
  @apply fade-slide translate-y-[20%];
}

.in-view {
  @apply translate-x-0 translate-y-0 opacity-100;
}
```

Can I somehow separate these two durations and have them be independent without adding additional wrappers around everything that has to be animated on hover alongside scroll animation.